# Is it possible to retrieve/log/monitor the kubernetes hpa controller recommendation map/list?

Tags: kubernetes, scaling, azure-aks, hpa

I'm currently troubleshooting the scaling behavior of some kubernetes deployments. I've configured the hpa with some scale down policies including the stabilizationWindowSeconds parameter. From the documentation I understood that the hpa controller tracks a recommendation list (I can also see this in the hpa controller code). To better understand why my scaling doesn't work as expected, I'd love to analyze this recommendation list. Is it possible to retrieve/log/monitor this list/map?